# Close Jquery UI tab, on dialog button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm using Jquery UI Tabs. This stays on my **index.jsp** where on click of the search button the following function gets called and a tab is added content is loaded.

```
function addTab(url, title) {
  var id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
    li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /~\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /~\{label\}/g, title ) ); tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
  tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p></p></div>" );
  $("#" + id).load(url);
  $("#accordion").accordion();
  tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
  tabCounter++;}
```

On successful search, it renders **success.jsp** into the tab. But in case of invalid input I'm rendering a **error.jsp** file which contains the following sample code.

```
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Quick Search">
<p>The entered ID was not found.</p>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$(function () {
$("#dialog").dialog({
buttons: {
          OK: function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
          }
       }     
});

});
</script>
```

On click of the dialog box I want it to close the dialog box, AND the tab it's in. I've tried a few possible solutions I've found online but didn't get it to work. Any help?

EDIT 1: Still no luck in finding an apt solution. Is there any more information that's required for someone to answer? Please let me know so that I can do so. Basically want to be able to close the tab, in which a dialog box is present, by clicking a button on the dialog box.

Comment: what your Jquery UI Tabs html?

Comment: Jquery UI Tabs is a widget from Jquery UI which I've used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var activeTab = tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-active" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
    $( "#" + activeTab).remove();
    tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
```

In case anyone else faces this issue,This worked for me. I'm getting the active tab the dialog is open in, removing the aria controls attribute which removes the tab, followed by removing the tab content itself.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do it :

1) After the page have been loaded in the new tab, add some static code inside the new tab. This code will be adapted with the tabs-'id' defined for the tab.

```
$("#" + id).load(url)
// something like :
$("#" + id).append('<a href="#" onclick="closetab(' + tabCounter + ')">close this tab</a>')
$("#accordion").accordion();
```

2) add to the url the tabCounter and modify the jsp page in order to use this tabCounter for killing it self.

```
url += "?"+tabCounter;
```

new JPS page returned by the server :

```
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Quick Search">
<p>The entered ID was not found.</p>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$(function () {
$("#dialog").dialog({
buttons: {
          OK: function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");

$("#tabs-38457").remove()
tabs.tabs( "refresh" );

          }
       }     
});

});
</script>
```

;)

Comment: I didn't quite get your first solution. The second one sort of works but I prefer not to pass the values as parameters each time. Is there another way? Also by this method I can remove the tab content, how do I remove the tab entry itself?